# How to search registered domain names without giving away the domain name

Tags: domain-name

I want to search registered domain names without giving out the search terms to a domain name registrar.

I need a trustworthy RPC database not an income-seeking company.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found it!  The internet domain name coordinator ICANN has a lookup function

```
https://lookup.icann.org
```

Comment: You can also simply use the `whois` tool

Comment: thankyou, that is also useful